# put list of objects in `Intent`

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I have a `liveData` in a ViewModel that return a list of object (`mChannelList: MutableLiveData<List<Channels>> = MutableLiveData()`). I want to send this list to another activity using the `putExtra` of `Intent`. I make the code below, but when the code pass in `startActivity` don´t go to the new activity (`MainActivity`).

I put list of objects in `Intent` corretly?

SplashScreenActivity.kt

```
(...)

            splashScreenViewModel.getList()?.observe(this, Observer { it : List<Channels> ->
                println("*********************** ${it}")
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_PEOPLE", ArrayList(it))
                startActivity(intent)
            })
```

The data class:

```
data class Channels (
    var Id: Int?,
    var Title: String?,
    var CallLetter: String?,
    var ChannelPosition: Int?
)
```

MainActivity.kt

```
(...)

val bundle = intent.extras
val arr = this.intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Parcelable>("EXTRA_PEOPLE")

println("a lista : ${arr[0]}")
```

Comment: I think you don't need to make that complicated. As you are using a ViewModel you could simply access it in your MainActivity. Remember to use Application's context when instantiating the ViewModel. See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) for more.

Comment: You're saying that your MainActivity is not starting when your observer fires? Or that you're not getting any data in MainActivity?

Comment: Yes, my MainActivity is not starting @JuanMartinez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to pass a list of objects between your activities. As @IlyaMaier said, a more robust way is to initialize your ViewModel with your application context and then reuse the same LiveData in your MainActivity.

if you want to continue the same way, there are two reasons why your MainActivity is not being called.

1. The observer is not being able to receive new data in your ViewModel Class.
2. The data class should extend Pacelable & also add annotation @Parcelize.

Like this:

```
@Parcelize
data class Channels (
var Id: Int?,
var Title: String?,
var CallLetter: String?,
var ChannelPosition: Int? 
) : Parcelable
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Implement Serializable to the Object class of your list**

```
public class ObjClassName implements Serializable {   
//your object class body    
}
```

**2. While sending list using intent**

```
List<ObjClassName> objList=new ArrayList<>();    
Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentScreen.this,NextScreen.class);        
        intent.putExtra("IDENTICAL_NAME",(Serializable)objList);    
        startActivity(intent);
```

**3. While retrieving list**

```
List<ObjClassName> objList=new ArrayList<>();       
        Intent intent = getIntent();    
        objList = (List<ObjClassName>)intent.getSerializableExtra("IDENTICAL_NAME");
```

This works for me!
Thanks